# ReactiveMongo BSONDouble vs BSONLong

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactive-programming

I have a large csv file which I converted to UTF8 via iconv and then loaded into Mongo. I'm getting lots of errors trying to query the data using ReactiveMongo / Scala. It seems that some records put in values as BSONDouble and some as BSONLong. Retrieving the query causes the error: BSONDouble cannot be cast to BSONLong or the other way around if I try to switch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me far down the rabbit hole. Not only were some of the numbers stored by mongoimport either BSONDouble or BSONLong or BSONInteger, some were even BSONString. I initially used BSONNumberLike checks and that worked for a small dataset, but then when I switched to the larger data set in mongo, it crashed with Null pointer exceptions. After more reading and looking at the returned BSONs, this code seems to be more bullet proof (or at least is working  with my large data set):

```
case class Aggsecrow (
  Strategy: String,
  Security: String,
  LocalPosn: Double,
  USDPosn: Double,
  CurrentPx: Double,
  USDMV: Double,
  PNL: Double
)

object Aggsecrow {
  implicit object AggsecrowBSONReader extends BSONDocumentReader[Aggsecrow] {
    def safeNumGet(field: String, doc: BSONDocument): Double = {
      var dtry = doc.getAsTry[BSONNumberLike](field)
      var d = 0.0
      if(dtry.isFailure) {
        val stry = doc.getAsTry[BSONString](field)
        val strConv = stry.get.value
        val doubleConv = Double.valueOf(strConv).longValue
        d = doubleConv.doubleValue
      } else {
        d = try {dtry.get.toDouble} catch { case _ => 0.0}
      }
      d
    }

    def read(doc: BSONDocument) :Aggsecrow = {
      Aggsecrow(
        doc.getAsTry[String]("Strategy").get,
        doc.getAsTry[String]("Security").get,
        safeNumGet("LocalPosn",doc) ,
        safeNumGet("USDPosn",doc) ,
        safeNumGet("Current",doc) ,
        safeNumGet("USDMV",doc) ,
        safeNumGet("PNL",doc) ,
    }
  }
```

Comment: This new function handles exponential numbers, like 1e7

Answer (score 2):

Hard to really help if you don't show some code. I assume you are writing a `BSONDocumentReader` for your document and you call `BSONDocument.getAs[A]` with `A` being either `BSONDouble` or `BSONLong` and it fails when the type doesn't match.

One way would be to use `BSONDocument.getAsTry[A]` which will return a `Try[A]` and if it's a `Failure` you know that you have to try the other type.

Comment: yes, i was using doc.get[BSONLong].colName   i switched to getAsTry earlier today. i have another avenue that might work. testing it now

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when running tests.
However, this was caused by a 'DataLoader' which injects data into the db before testing. Data was injected as *json* and therefore a '0' was interpreted as an Integer instead of a Double.

Changing the '0' to '0.1' in the test data was enough to force the type to be a Double in Mongo. Now retrieving the document retrieved the value as BSONDouble.